# Loaded: Bad-setting ( Reason unit tomcat.service has bad unit file setting.) am using ubuntu20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, services, execute-command, tomcat8

[that is the error coming out after trying to run tomcat with sudo systemctl status tomcat]

```
[output]
tunji@tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4:~$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
tunji@tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4:~$ sudo systemctl status tomcat
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of tomcat.service ch>
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit tomcat.service has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

May 06 06:52:43 tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51CD.jpg): /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.s>
May 06 06:52:43 tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51CD.jpg): tomcat.service: Service has >
May 06 06:53:32 tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51CD.jpg): /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.s>
May 06 06:53:32 tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51CD.jpg): tomcat.service: Service has >
May 06 07:06:33 tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51CD.jpg): /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.s>
May 06 07:06:33 tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51CD.jpg): tomcat.service: Service has >
May 06 07:27:13 tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51CD.jpg): tomcat.service: Service has >
May 06 07:27:47 tunji-HP-EliteBook-840-G4 systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51CD.jpg): tomcat.service: Service has >

……………………………………………..

[my unit file]

```
Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom'

Environment=CATALINA_PID=/var/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Please don't add terminal/text output as screenshots. Copy it as text into your question, and format it appropriately.

Comment: Please show the full uotput, including the command. Your picture shows a configuration file, not an error.

Comment: yea I have edit the questions and copy as text

Comment: I have formatted your update a little. The error seems to be in your unit-file. Of what you show, I can only see a missing `[` in the beginning ... Unit] instead of [Unit] but that could be missing due to cut&paste ?

Comment: even after adding the ' [ ' in the beginning still giving the same error